# colored, numbered circles in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Since some days I see those Circles at the left side of Visual Studios Editor.
I'm using Visual Studio 2019, Version 16.9.2. I think those circles came with some update of some component but I don't know wher they mean and what they are good for?

[image]

Comment: Do you get a tooltip when you hover the mouse over the them?

Comment: there is no tooltip. I get the circles on every method. Maybe these circles are the results of some "Code Metrics Analysys" showing some kind of methods complexity?